# Utcoffset formats in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

```
var utcOffset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(((utcOffset < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "+") + utcOffset.ToString("hhmm"));
```

The above code is working fine. But I need to display offset like +05:00. Is there any way to achieve this format?

Comment: Just use `hh':'mm` as the format string? Also, use `TimeZoneInfo` rather than `TimeZone`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but doesn't work that way. Like, utcOffset.ToString("hh:mm"));

Comment: Read my comment again. I did not say `hh:mm`.

Comment: Like,  Console.WriteLine(((utcOffset.BaseUtcOffset < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "+") + utcOffset.BaseUtcOffset.Hours + ":" + utcOffset.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes);
//output is +5:0, I am trying your suggestion of TimeZoneInfo
But i need +05:00

Comment: I meant `utcOffset.ToString("hh':'mm"));`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings):

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers don't include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals.

So you have to escape character in your format string that is not listed in the above page, either by surrounding it with `'`, or with a backslash, so:

```
utcOffset.ToString("hh':'mm")
```

However, you don't actually have to do this formatting yourself, if you format a `DateTimeOffset`, rather than `TimeSpan`. If you do this, you don't need all the "getting the UTC offset" mess either.

You just need the [zzz Custom Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier):

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("zzz")
```

You don't need all of the `TimeZone` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `TimeZone` to look up the timezone from `DateTime.Now`, you can use `DateTimeOffset.Now` with the `zzz` format string and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to achieve this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("HHmmzzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// outputs 1255+02:00
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/UQPZ54085)

If you just want the offset in that format, you can use `"zzz"` instead of `"HHmmzzzz"`.

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? I m not getting the same output as yours. It says the input string was not in the correct format. Thank-you.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `.Now`. Can you try again?